# Method to display the liquidity added in DEX

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain

I am new to DEX development. Am using pancakeswap router contract https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xd99d1c33f9fc3444f8101754abc46c52416550d1

addLiquidityETH is working to add the liquidity in the DEX. I need to display a list. Which method I need to use in router or factory contract to display the liquidity added details like below image

Thanks in Advance

[image: Liquidity List]

Comment: How are you trying to call these functions? Solidity (in your own contract), or a web3 library?

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti Using ethers.js.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa Pl.Help me to achieve this...